# Problema com batch de arquivo python ao ativar gerenciador de tarefas do windows

Tags: python, batch

Fiz um arquivo batch para rodar um pequeno script em python, ele funciona normalmente, mas quando uso agendador de tarefas do windows para acionar o batch em um horario especifico ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde fala que o erro esta nessa linha, mas não consigo ver nada de errado nela:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path=r'C:\\scrapy\\geckodriver.exe', firefox_profile = profile)
```

Pesquisei sobre e falaram que problema com permissão do usuário, mas estou usando um usuário que é adm

Comment: Acredito que o erro esteja relacionada a não execução como adm (super usuário).

Comment: mas estou como adm e nao vai

Comment: ja sim e ja tentei, nao deu certo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirme se as opções abaixo estão marcadas nas propriedades da tarefa agendada.

[image: Configuração das propriedades da tarefa agendada]

Outro problema é que para o batch chamar um segundo programa como administrador teria de se utilizar algo como:

```
runas /user:maquina\administrador programa.exe
```

o que acaba gerando um prompt pedindo a senha do administrador. Para que o prompt seja apresentado apenas uma vez use:

```
runas /savecred /user:maquina\administrador programa.exe
```

Então execute o batch e preencha a senha do administrador. Nas próximas execuções não será mais solicitada a senha.

Comment: A configuração estava certo, o problema do runas é que a gpo da empresa bloqueia o uso dele, então tenho que pensar em outra solução, mas como a sua resposta resolveria o problema da grande maioria vou marcar como certa